# Do people who like Lil Wayne score low in the SAT?

Tags: education

I found a picture on facebook quoting results of a recent study.

[image]

It states that,

> A study found that people who said their favourite music is by Lil Wayne scored the lowest on the SAT.

Has anyone established a correlation between liking Lil Wayne and scores in the SAT? Has such a study been conducted?

Comment: Note to researchers: wackfact.com currently redirects to a virus scam site, as do all the links on its extant Facebook page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The source of this factoid is [musicthatmakesyoudumb](http://musicthatmakesyoudumb.virgil.gr/), a site run by an American software developer.

His process was to, for each college, get the most popular artists according that college's student's Facebook profiles, and to correlate those against the average SAT score for that college.

This would be better boiled down as "People who go colleges with the lowest admission requirements are more likely to say they like Lil Wayne on their Facebook profile".

The research is not peer reviewed, and has not accounted for any confounding factors.

Comment: Good answer.  I won't give the website developer the satisfaction of a click, simply because of the stupid name of the site.  Rather like saying tall people hit their heads on doorways more than short people, therefore hitting your head on doorways makes you taller.

Comment: @Mark, well, obviously correlation doesn't mean causation, but as far as methods go, this isn't a horrible one. I'm not saying lil wayne makes you dumber, but it may be that those with less drive -> i.e didn't study for the SAT, are more inclined to listen to lil wayne. Again obviously not something we can study here but would be interesting to look at none the less.

Comment: @Mark you're going to love this question: [Does playing basketball help you grow taller?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39671/does-playing-basketball-help-you-grow-taller)